# Distribute responsibilities between related interfaces

Tags: java, class, methods, reflection, interface

I have two related interfaces, but I am unsure about how to distribute some responsibilities (methods).

Lets say that one interface is Truck, and the other is ParkingLot.

There can be different implementations of Truck, like DumpTruck, BoxTruck, FireTruck..., and different implementations of ParkingLot like TruckParkingLot, CarParkingLot, MotorcycleParkingLot...

I have a program is basically a TruckParkingLot, and it consists in the following:

```
 private Map<String, Truck> trucks = new ConcurentHashMap();

 public void registerTruck(String plate, Truck truck) {
      // Code to put a new Truck in the ParkingLot
 }

 public void removeTruck(String plate) {
      // Code to remove a Truck from the ParkingLot
 }

 public Truck getTruckByPlate(String plate) {
      // Code to get Truck with key (plate) from the Map trucks
  }
```

Then there is the Truck interface, which has several implementations. Each implementation differs from the other because they have different instance variables.

I want to also implement two other methods: update and print. The former updates the instance variables of the selected Truck; the latter prints the instance variables of the selected Truck.

The doubt that I have is if these methods should be in the ParkingLot interface or in the Truck interface.

On one hand I feel these methods should be in the ParkingLot interface, so the client only has to access the TruckParkingLot y classes to get all the information it wants and to manage it. Furthermore, with reflect you can easily manage any instance of a class (including private) without knowing how many instance variables or which instance variables does the given object have.

On the other, by putting these two methods in the ParkingLot interface this interface then manages data that isn't built-in the TruckParkingLot, but is from the instance variables of a given Truck, violating the responsibility-driven design principles (the private class instances should only be dealt within the class to which they belong). Also, if update and print go to the ParkingLot interface, then the Truck interface becomes an empty interface (there are no more methods for Truck).

On a third hand, if I implement these two methods in the Truck interface, then I would be duplicating code for each implementation of this interface, since the way to update or print the instance variables of a BoxTruck and a DumpTruck is almost the same if it is done with getters and setters (and completely the same if it is done with reflection)

Another possible solution would be to create an abstract class for Truck and implement update and print methods, and the rest of the trucks just inherit this class. (Should I still had to create an interface for this abstract class?).

In summary, I had these options in mind when I first wrote this post:

A) ParkingLot interface with all methods; Truck interface with no methods (empty).

```
 interface ParkingLot {
     public void registerVehicle(String plate, Vehicle vehicle);
     public void removeVehicle(String plate);
     public Vehicle getVehicleByPlate(String plate);
     public void updateVehicle(Vehicle vehicle);
     public void printVehicleData(Vehicle vehicle);
 }

 public class TruckParkingLot implements ParkingLot {
     private Map<String, Truck> trucks = new ConcurentHashMap();

     public void registerVehicle(String plate, Vehicle truck) {
         // Code to put a new Truck in the ParkingLot
     }

     public void removeVehicle(String plate) {
          // Code to remove a Truck from the ParkingLot
     }

     public Truck getVehicleByPlate(String plate) {
         // Code to get Truck with key (plate) from the Map trucks
     }

     public Truck updateVehicle(Vehicle truck) {
         // Code to update the inst vars of a Truck using reflection
     }

     public Truck printVehicleData(Vehicle truck) {
         // Code to print the inst vars of a Truck using reflection
     }
 }

 interface Truck extends Vehicle {
     // Nothing here
 }

 public class DumpTruck implements Truck {
     // Private instance variables
     // Constructor
     // Setters and getters
 }

 public class BoxTruck implements Truck {
     // Other private instance variables
     // Another constructor
     // Setters and getters
 }
```

B) ParkingLot interface with it's methods, Truck interface with update and print methods.

```
 interface ParkingLot {
     public void registerVehicle(String plate, Vehicle vehicle);
     public void removeVehicle(String plate);
     public Vehicle getVehicleByPlate(String plate);
 }

 public class TruckParkingLot implements ParkingLot {
     private Map<String, Truck> trucks = new ConcurentHashMap();

     public void registerVehicle(String plate, Vehicle truck) {
         // Code to put a new Truck in the ParkingLot
     }

     public void removeVehicle(String plate) {
          // Code to remove a Truck from the ParkingLot
     }

     public Truck getVehicleByPlate(String plate) {
         // Code to get Truck with key (plate) from the Map trucks
     }
 }

 interface Truck extends Vehicle {
     public void updateVehicle(Vehicle vehicle);
     public void printVehicleData(Vehicle vehicle); 
     // Both methods should actually be inherited from Vehicle
     // interface, but this doesn't affect the point here.
     // Technically the Truck methods would still be empty.
 }

 public class DumpTruck implements Truck {
      // Private instance variables
      // Constructor
      // Setters and getters

      public Truck updateVehicle(Vehicle truck) {
          // Code to update the inst var using setters and getters
      }

     public Truck printVehicleData(Vehicle truck) {
         // Code to print the inst var using setters and getters
     }
 }

 public class BoxTruck implements Truck {
     // Other private instance variables
     // Another constructor
     // Setters and getters

     public Truck updateVehicle(Vehicle truck) {
         // Code to update the inst vars using setters and getters
     }

     public Truck printVehicleData(Vehicle truck) {
         // Code to print the inst vars using setters and getters
     }
 }
```

C) ParkingLot interface with it's methods, Truck abstract class.

```
interface ParkingLot {
     public void registerVehicle(String plate, Vehicle vehicle);
     public void removeVehicle(String plate);
     public Vehicle getVehicleByPlate(String plate);
 }

 public class TruckParkingLot implements ParkingLot {
     private Map<String, Truck> trucks = new ConcurentHashMap();

     public void registerVehicle(String plate, Vehicle truck) {
         // Code to put a new Truck in the ParkingLot
     }

     public void removeVehicle(String plate) {
          // Code to remove a Truck from the ParkingLot
     }

     public Truck getVehicleByPlate(String plate) {
         // Code to get Truck with key (plate) from the Map trucks
     }
 }

 public abstract class Truck implements Vehicle {
     // private common instance variables to all trucks
     // Constructor with all common instance variables
     // Setters and getters

     public Truck updateVehicle(Vehicle truck) {
         // Code to update the inst vars using setters and getters
     }

     public Truck printVehicleData(Vehicle truck) {
         // Code to print the inst vars using setters and getters
     }
 }

 public class DumpTruck implements Truck {
     // Private unique instance variables to DumpTruck
     // Inherit constructor from superclass
     // + initialize unique instance variables for this subclass
     // Setters and getters for the unique inst vars of this subclass

     @override
     public Truck updateVehicle(Vehicle truck) {
         // inherit code from superclass 
        // + update the unique instance variables of this subclass
     }

     @override
     public Truck printVehicleData(Vehicle truck) {
         // inherit code from superclass
         // + print the unique instance variables of this subclass
     }
 }

 public class BoxTruck implements Truck {
     // Private unique instance variables to DumpTruck
     // Inherit constructor from superclass
     // + initialize unique instance variables for this subclass
     // Setters and getters for the unique inst vars of this subclass

     @override
     public Truck updateVehicle(Vehicle truck) {
         // inherit code from superclass
         // + update the unique instance variables of this subclass
     }

     @override
     public Truck printVehicleData(Vehicle truck) {
         // inherit code from superclass
         // + print the unique instance variables of this subclass
     }
 }
```

Personally, I prefer to have all methods in the ParkingLot interface and use reflection (option A), leaving the Truck interface empty; or using an abstract class for Truck (option C)

But, really, I am not sure about anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that true OOP design calls for Types to closely mimic the real world objects they represent.  I assume that when update() gets called you intend on retrieving some values from a data store that then in turn updates the instance variables.  If this is correct, it makes your objects mutable which can be bad design.

The way I look at it, trucks come out of a garage and go into a garage in the real world and that is what your object structure should do too.  You can "update" your Truck by passing the truck into the Garage interface.  And in order for the Truck to be immutable the method then passes back an instance of the new Truck.  For instance:

```
interface Garage {
        Truck service(final Truck truck);
}
```

Where the service method is your "update" method but also more closely mimics the real world domain.   As far as printing goes, I would suggest that would be another class altogether and this class's constructor would be overloaded for the various types of trucks so you can handle them separately in a divergent way.

```
interface TruckPrinter {
        void print();
}
class BasicTruckPrinter implements TruckPrinter {
        private String output;
        BasicTruckPrinter(final DumpTruck truck) { /* convert truck to output */ }
        BasicTruckPrinter(final FireTruck truck) { ... }
        BasicTruckPrinter(final BoxTruck truck) { ... }

        void print() {
              System.out.println(output);
        }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks for your answer, specially for the part about print. I have noticed a huge mistake I made in the question that has lead to a misunderstanding. By Garage I meant Parking Lot (in Spanish the word for an underground or covered parking lot is "garaje", hence my mistranslation). I corrected it in the original post. This means that the Garage itself doesn't offer the service of updating anything.

Comment: I still think its important to have a place in your object model for your Truck objects to be "updated" in a way that makes sense with the real world domain.  What kind of internal data will they be updating ? can you explain?

Comment: I made a huge edit to the main post, I believe it is easier bto understand now. They would be updating data like brand, motor power, height... Basically the private instance variables of any given Truck